# how to use datagrid view cells?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, linq-to-entities

```
for (int  i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

                it = db.items.FirstOrDefault(p => p.rakmsanf == Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value ));
            {

                it.quantity =(Convert .ToInt32 ( it.quantity )+Convert.ToInt32 ( dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value)).ToString ();
            }
```

trying to use column2 value to update

Quantity and make it = Quantity +column2 value which item name = other value in other column
i get

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

[image]

Comment: I tried to format your code, but I think you have an error in where you are putting your braces.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell how you're code's supposed to be formatted exactly, but try doing the string conversion first, then using the result of that in the LINQ statement.

It seems that EF is trying to convert your `Convert.ToString()` into LINQ, and it can't.

```
for (int  i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var cellValue = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value);

    it = db.items.FirstOrDefault(p => p.rakmsanf == cellValue);
}
```